# CC Email is not receiving c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, sendgrid

```
string Body = "Test Body";
string Subject = "Subject";
string FromAddress = "Name@Domain.com"
string ToAddress = "To@Domain.com"
string CcAddress = "Cc@Domain.com"

 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
  msg.Subject = Subject;
  msg.Body = Body;
  msg.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
  msg.To.Add(ToAddress);
  msg.CC.Add(CcAddress);

 client.Send(msg);
```

To Email is receiving but cc Email is not receiving. Is there any missing line or code?

Comment: `msg.CC.Add(CcAddress);`? I can't see where `Cc` is defined.

Comment: Read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.cc?view=netcore-3.1) when in doubt.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `CC` is property of `MailMessage` object. To add a CC recipient to an email message, create a MailAddress for the recipient's address and then add that object to the collection returned by the `CC` property.

Comment: @Rahul He's updated the question; originally he had put `msg.CC.Add(Cc);`.

Comment: @RahulSharma : it's working.